# jasmine test doesn't see object results while the function return object

Tags: javascript, jasmine

i have the following simple JS function that return an object

```
async create(o: Order): Promise<Order> {
try {
  const conn = await client.connect();
  const checkActiveQuery = "SELECT id FROM orders WHERE userId = $1 AND currentStatus = $2;";
  const checkActiveQueryRes = await conn.query(checkActiveQuery, [o.userId, o.currentStatus,]); 
  if (checkActiveQueryRes.rows[0]) {
    console.log('True Already Existed Active order')
    conn.release();
    throw new Error('an active order for this user already exists');
  } else {
    console.log('started to failllllll here')
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO orders (userId, currentStatus) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *;';
    const result = await conn.query(sql, [o.userId, o.currentStatus]);
    conn.release();
    const order = result.rows[0];
    console.log('new order has: ' + order)
    console.log(order)
    console.log(order.id)
    return (order);
  }
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error(`Cannot create order: ${err}`);
}}
```

while i am trying to test it using jasmine specs as following

```
  it('create method should add an order', async () => {
    const order: Order = await orderStore.create({userId: 1, currentStatus: 'active'})
    expect(order).toEqual({id: 1, userId: 1, currentStatus: 'active',})
  })
```

i got the following console error from the spec itself as if it doesn't see results

Order model method create method should add an order

```
  - Expected object to have properties
      userId: 1
      currentStatus: 'active'
  Expected object not to have properties
      userid: '1'
      currentstatus: 'active'
```

Wile i made the function to return three kinds of result.rows[0] object as it return here
in console

```
new order has: [object Object] ==> order object var in console.log('new or...' + order)
{ id: 1, userid: null, currentstatus: null } ==> order object in console.log(order)
1 ==> picked up order.id
```

what's the difference between the 1st two lines of order variable and why not explicitly has the same properties shown in console and what to do to make this test success
please any help, i would be grateful to you

[console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5JX6.png)